# Civilization V Steam workshop troubles

Tags: steam, civilization-5, technical-issues

So I have two different questions.

1. When I download maps from steam workshop and try to run them there are no options to select the map I had downloaded when browsing maps. What could cause this or what am I doing wrong? Specific maps being the Cataclysm Map Pack and Shinnoh Region map, note that I do have BNW installed and working.
2. My Civilization V won't run on the recommended setting anymore, I click on the option and the program won't start up anymore. It used to but now it doesn't, what's the issue with it?

Thank you,

Rave!

Comment: You have to acrivate the mods first in order to Play them. Go there through the main menu (should be Name just "MODS"), check your mod and then go on "NExt" (or "PLAY"?). Then it takes several seconds to load. You then should have your new maps there as the map type (!) or as a Szenario.

Comment: I do that but when I look for the map among those available it's not there. Thank though.

Comment: I'm not at home. Otherwise I would like to hear the Name of the mod to look myself, sry.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Civilization V installed on a drive other than C:, when you activate the maps it tries to place them in drive C instead of the one your game is installed in. Every time you want to play a brand new map you'd have to go to my games > Civ V > MODS, and copy the .Civ5Map file.
Then you have to paste in in Steam > steamapps > common > Civilization V > assets > maps.